# How to inject actions before CRUD in Abp.IRepository<TEntity>

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I'm using Volo.Abp 3.0.4 (Abp framework). I need to create some actions that will happen before some methods in IRepository classes - CreateAsync, UpdateAsync, etc. But I just can't override a repository because my clients should need more than one of those actions.

Those actions are range from get some information about the entity (TEntity) and trigger some action to just log something before really hits database. This is not a problem about inheritance but composition - I have a chain of actions to do and clients will be able to choice those ones.

So my question is: how can I achieve that in a easy way and extendable? Thank you guys!

Edit: I was thinking that I could override the method I want once and inside of it, get all objects that implement an interface and run them on sequence. Is this a good approach or is there something already implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Some events are automatically triggered when you make changes on entities, these events emit event data objects which are `EntityCreatingEventData<TEntity>, EntityCreatedEventData<TEntity>, EntityUpdatingEventData<TEntity>, EntityUpdatedEventData<TEntity>, EntityDeletingEventData<TEntity>, EntityDeletedEventData<TEntity>, EntityChangingEventData<TEntity>, EntityChangedEventData<TEntity>`

'**ing**' events (e.g. EntityUpdating) are triggered **before** committing a transaction while '**ed**' events (e.g. EntityUpdated) are triggered **after** committing a transaction.

You can create eventhandlers to subscribe to these events. For example,

```
public class MyHandler : ILocalEventHandler<EntityCreatedEventData<IdentityUser>>, ITransientDependency
{
    public async Task HandleEventAsync(EntityCreatedEventData<IdentityUser> eventData)
    {
        var userName = eventData.Entity.UserName;
        var email = eventData.Entity.Email;
        //...
    }
}
```

[View more detail in their document](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Local-Event-Bus#pre-built-events).

**NOTE**: After version `3.0` released, they required extra configuration to enable the built-in events. So, just add this configuration in a module class, the *...DomainModule* is appropriated.

```
public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
{
    ...
    
    Configure<AbpDistributedEntityEventOptions>(options =>
    {
        //Enable for all entities
        options.AutoEventSelectors.AddAll();
    });
}
```

[View more detail about the configuration](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/4411).

Comment: Can I create these events for generic objects and then use it for entities which implements an interface?

Comment: Yes, you can publish any event of your choice, view an example in https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Local-Event-Bus#publishing-events. Then subscribe to the event with event-handler, view an example in https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Local-Event-Bus#subscribing-to-events